# Problem at log on: AppData

Tags: windows-7, login

Please can you help me solve the following, every time I log on the following pops up:

```
There was a problem starting
C:\Users\MarkFarmer1\AppData\Roaming\mouse1.dll
The specified module could not be found.
```

How do I sort it? I would be grateful for anyones help!

Answer (score 2):

That's dialog box is coming from a program that runs on startup.  Unfortunately it provides no information about what program is launching it, and looks suspiciously like part of a virus that might have been removed, as normal programs don't generally drop DLLS in your AppData directory.  (They've been known to do worse things though, so it's impossible to be sure.)

You can use the [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) tool from Microsoft to manage all the programs that are configured to run at startup.  I suggest you use the *Hide Signed Windows Entries* option to eliminate built-in Windows components from the listing to make it easier.

Try removing programs that you don't need to run at startup and see if it goes away.  (Since this program isn't working you must not be using it.  :-)  You should also consider uninstalling any programs you don't use them at all.

If it persists, you will need to run each of the remaining ones to figure out which is generating that error.  Once you figure it out, you can disable automatic startup, uninstall the program, or reinstall it or look in to why it's causing that error.